# How to populate a map in Java 8?

Tags: java, algorithm, java-8

```
private static Map<Character, Integer> populateMap(List<Character> chars) {
    final Map<Character, Integer> inputStringCountMap  = new HashMap<Character, Integer>();
    for (Character ch : chars) {
        int val = 0;
        if (inputStringCountMap.containsKey(ch)) {
            val = inputStringCountMap.get(ch);
        }
        inputStringCountMap.put(ch, val + 1);
    }

    return inputStringCountMap;
}
```

The above function simply populates the Map with the count of each `char`.
Is there a shorter / cleaner way to do this in Java 8?

Comment: I should point out that `populateMap` is a terrible name for a method - it leads to the question "populate with what?"

Answer (score 11, accepted):

```
 private static Map<Character, Long> populateMap(List<Character> chars) {

    return chars.stream()
            .collect(Collectors.groupingBy(Function.identity(), Collectors.counting()));

}
```

Answer (score 5):

If you're OK with a `Map<Character, Long>`, a grouping collector with a counting subcollector should do it:

```
Map<Character, Long> result = chars.stream().collect(
    Collectors.groupingBy(Function.identity(), Collectors.counting());
```

If you require the value type to be `Integer`, this can be done with a map collector:

```
Map<Character, Integer> result = chars.stream().collect(
    Collectors.toMap(Function.identity(), c -> 1, Integer::sum);
```

Answer (score 3):

You can try something like this.

```
Map<Character,Integer> myFreq= new HashMap<>();
for (char ch : input.toCharArray()) {
    myFreq.put(ch, myFreq.getOrDefault(ch, 0) + 1);
}
```

Comment: But, there's no Java 8 concept involved in this

Comment: I just provide a cleaner way to achieve the question's way.

Comment: The OP specifically asks about a cleaner way in Java 8. He's more interested in streams I guess.

Answer (score 1):

Here is another way

```
for (Character ch : chars) {
    inputStringCountMap.merge(ch, 1, (a, b) -> a+b);
}
```

Comment: The lambda function does not take `(key, value)` as parameters, but rather `(oldValue, newValue)`.  Also, why 10 to start?

Comment: Yeah thanks. I did that on autopilot. And the 10 was a typo.

Comment: `b+1` is also likely to be incorrect, as this will always result in 2.

Comment: True again. I need to get some sleep I think. Thanks for all the help. I fixed it now.